# The anchors element move up when i use overflow property

Tags: html, css

**My problem and the reason of it:**

I have this html:

```
<div class="container">
    List of anchors:
    <a href="#" class="child">First child</a>
    <a href="#" class="child">Second child</a>
</div>
```

and these styles:

```
.child {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  overflow: hidden; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

But, for some reason, the anchors it strangely moves up, [you can see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkeDr.png).
And, I found out that this problem happens because of the `overflow` property, i tried to remove it and [this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQXmm.png), which also what I expected. But of course, I really need the `overflow` property, so I can't move on without it.

**The reason I need to use the overflow property:**
I want to use it because I want to make the effect, when I hover each anchor, there will be a line under it moves from left to right.
So I will use the `::after` pesudo element, translate it 100% (`transform: translateX(-100%)`) to the left and when hover it, it would move back to 0% (`transform: translateX(0%)`). So the overflow property would hide the `::after` pesudo element when it translate 100% to the left.

**What I tried:**
I tried to use the `ul` element instead, an wrap each anchors into each `li` element:

```
<ul class="list">
    List of anchors:
    <li class="child-list"><a href="#" class="child-anchor">First child</a></li>
    <li class="child-list"><a href="#" class="child-anchor">Second child</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
.child-anchor {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child-list {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

But, that it still moves up.

**What I want to know:**
I want to know why this weird problem happens, and also the way to fix it, or some other ways to make the effect that I mentioned in the *The reason I need to use the overflow property* section. So hopefully, you guys can help me with this and thank you so much for spending time reading this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried :

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, I fixed now, can you tell me why this happen, and why this vertical-align: middle fix this problem? Thank you so so much again!

Comment: To be honest, i dont have any idea ^^ most of the time vertical align seems to be useless BUT for this thing its working, have a good day :)